# In React-Native When Android device is disconnected through usb cable. shows weird behaviour

Tags: react-native

I run react-native code on phone which is connected through usb cable. I run using command react-native run-android .. it is working perfectly fine.

**It shows weird behaviour when I disconnected my phone. 
I removed my usb cable and give that app for testing .**

1 What I see button is not clickable.

2 View Pager is implemented on screen is miss behaving.(Means functionality doesn't work properly)

3 When I kill the app and reopen it, that shows me the behaviour which I implemented 2 weeks back.

Even When i run app from Android studio same behaviour shows as shown in 3rd points.

it works fine when my phone is connect through usb cable even on emulator it is working fine.

Please help me as I am unable to give my app in QA as it showing in-appropriate behaviour when phone is not connected through usb cable

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you are using a development version, I would say that geting disconnected from the develoment server implies facing unexpected behaviour.

If you want to run your application for a demonstration or anything else, without having to connect to the development server, you can generate a signed apk and install it on your phone :

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android

See this link for a complete explanation on how to do it.

Comment: I built app from Android studio using Build apk. Still its showing apk with old code

Comment: @Tarun try to build your apk Facebook's way, and tell me if you are still encountering the same issue